# Download ios 7 apps how?

Tags: iphone

I have a iphone 3gs which has a ios 6.1.6.
I want to download ios 7 to run applications like Facebook, SoundCloud, etc. 
But it cant be downloaded on my device which seems fully updated.

How may I upgrade it?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Apps requiring iOS 7 can't be installed on any version of iOS prior to iOS 7.